# How to add Django ldap users to Django ModelBackend Groups

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-login

I am running Django-1.7.7 with ModelBackend(default) with few users and 2 groups.

Now i have implemented Ldap Backend too with Model Backend. 
But after that i have to add all of the Ldap Authenticated users to one of the Model group automatically, when the users Authenticated.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this package:
https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/

and at this old post:
https://www.djm.org.uk/posts/using-django-auth-ldap-active-directory-ldaps/

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid storing users in model, using Django LDAP features. You should "ask" to your LDAP server if that user´s credentials are correct and then you can your do your stuff: Store the username in a variable session, redirect to specific pages, in every page you can check if variable session with username is correct, and so on,...

--SETTINGS.PY--

```
# LDAP Configuration.
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

# Binding and connection options.

# Address (by IP or Hostname) of LDAP Server (Directory Active)
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://xxx.xxx.x.xxx"
# DN of user through we bind to LDAP Server.
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "CN=xxx, CN=xxx, DC=xxx, DC=xxx"
# Password of user through we bind to LDAP Server.
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "xxxxxx"
# Node where we start to search users. Use to be DN (of random user) without the last one parameter.
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("CN=xxx, DC=xxx, DC=xxx", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(samAccountName=%(user)s)")
```

Then you can use it in your views, for checking is a specific user exists:

--VIEWS.PY--

```
con = ldap.initialize("ldap://ldapserver")
con.simple_bind_s( userDN, passwordUser )
filter = '(sAMAccountName=' + "loginName" + ')'
user = con.search_s( base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs )
con.unbind()
```